# Optimal parameter $\alpha$ for exponential smoothing using least squares

Tags: time-series, estimation, optimization

I was reading about [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) on Wikipedia.  I saw a sentence saying that I could find the optimal parameter $\alpha$ by using the method of least squares.  How do I go about doing that?  Are there other ways I can find the right $\alpha$?

**Edit:** Also, if possible, I'd like a way to handle missing values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minimize the sum of squared one-step forecast errors. If $\hat{Y}_t$ is the prediction of $Y_t$ given $Y_1,\dots,Y_{t-1}$, then $e_t=Y_t-\hat{Y}_t$ is the one-step forecast error. So minimize $e_2^2+\cdots+e_n^2$.

You can also use maximum likelihood estimation as discussed in [my Springer book](http://www.exponentialsmoothing.net).

If you're just using simple exponential smoothing, and are happy to assume normal errors with constant variance, then an ARIMA(0,1,1) model is equivalent.

When you use a state space representation (such as in the innovations state space form, or by writing the ARIMA model in state space form), then handling missing values is easy. For example, the R function `arima()` will handle missing values without complaint.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a bit slow.  How do I do the minimization? Is there a formula or an algorithm that I need to use?

Comment: You need to use a nonlinear optimization algorithm.

Comment: Okay. I've got as far as using ARIMA(0,1,1).  I am assuming that the code, arima(x, order = c(0, 1, 1)) is how one does that.  (I spent a few hours learning R first so I am completely new to this.) How do I apply the output to my smoothing problem?

Comment: Using R's parameterization, $\alpha = 1+\theta$ where $\theta$ is the moving average parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Great! I get it now.  My last hurdle is the missing values.  Now I have $\alpha$.  How do handle the missing values? Using the notation on Wikipedia, does this mean I have several $x_0$'s and I just restart the exponential smoothing algorithm after each gap?

Comment: arima() will handle the missing values appropriately. There's no need for you to do anything. Just use the forecasts it provides.