# When optimizing $\alpha$ in a simple exponential smoothing model, is there any benefit to using something more sophisticated than least squares?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, maximum-likelihood, aic, exponential-smoothing

I am trying to manually implement simple exponential smoothing, for which the formula is pretty straightforward:

$\hat{Y}_{t+1} = \alpha Y + (1- \alpha) \hat{Y}_t$

In the original formulation, the method was a heuristic and $\alpha$ was decided arbitrarily, with lower $\alpha$ values giving more weight to past values and higher $\alpha$ giving more weight to recent values (i.e. making the model more reactive).

More recent approaches try to optimize the value of $\alpha$ based on some accuracy metric. One way to do so is [using least squares](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/optimal-parameter-alpha-for-exponential-smoothing-using-least-squares?rq=1). Or one can use more sophisticated approaches based on information criteria, etc... for example the forecast package in R uses maximum likelihood to find the best $\alpha$.

I am puzzled: Since the output of simple exponential smoothing is a constant value, and the model has only one degree of freedom, is there any real benefit to using anything other than least squares?

Calculating something like the AIC or the BIC seems useless, since the model is already as parsimonious as it gets. Is there any purpose to using one of those metrics instead of a simple RMSE for finding $\alpha$?

Or do they mean anything at all, since with only one degree of freedom, minimizing the least squares and minimizing the AIC or the BIC amounts to the same thing?

Comment: Do you mean $\hat{Y}_{t+1} = \alpha Y + (1- \alpha) \hat{Y}_t$ rather than $\hat{Y}_t+1 = \alpha Y + (1- \alpha) \hat{Y}_t$?